# Leaks while executing sort

Tags: c, sorting, valgrind

I have a file with records and want to sort them out, by calling `sort` inside my project. Everything seems fine when running the program, but while trying to check for `leaks` with `valgrind`, I get a lot of errors. This is the code I use for executing:

`execlp("sort", "-g", "results", (char*) NULL);`

`results` is the file I want sorted out.

And there are the errors.

```
==27691== 
==27691== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27691==     in use at exit: 1,352 bytes in 17 blocks
==27691==   total heap usage: 66 allocs, 49 frees, 44,055 bytes allocated
==27691== 
==27691== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4110C8: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x402FFD: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4110C8: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x40D33C: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x4046A2: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== 88 bytes in 12 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4110C8: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x402D66: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4C2FDEF: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x411125: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x405D89: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x4043C0: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 5 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4110C8: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x4046D4: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== 1,120 (32 direct, 1,088 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==27691==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27691==    by 0x4110C8: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x40D313: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x4046A2: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==27691==    by 0x507782F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==27691== 
==27691== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27691==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==27691==    indirectly lost: 1,088 bytes in 2 blocks
==27691==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27691==    still reachable: 216 bytes in 13 blocks
==27691==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27691== 
==27691== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27691== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am not mallocing any pointers and it seems like there errors are out of my reach since they do not appear inside my project.

Comment: All of these are in /usr/bin/sort. Unless you took up a new career managing that utility this doesn't appear to be in your wheelhouse. And props for using valgrind, btw.

Comment: Those are issues with the sort program, not your code.

Comment: they do not look even look like real issues in "sort'. Just few blocks which it did not bother to delete before exit. Anyway, as mentioned above, it is not your problem.

Comment: In addition to @Serge: When a process is terminated, the OS does a final clean-up of resources that have been used in that process exclusively (e.g. allocated memory, file handles, etc.) This doesn't look that nice in Valgrind but isn't critical for your application (which is running in another process) nor for anything else in your system.